# RAML connection setup in salesforce

Tags: rest-api

Can anyone please help me in setting up raml connection in salesforce?
We have RAML file shared to us which has details of external system.
But we dont know the steps to establish connection using that RAML which enables us to get the data from external system into salesforce.

Comment: Hello Mahesh, Please explain specific problem you are facing instead of asking for full implementation information

Comment: here i wan to know if we first need to configure endpoint url in remote site in salesforce and then can we send the request to get data or do we need to do any additional  setup like setup authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our chat conversion, i would suggest you do some trailheads on integration to understand how to integrate with external systems.

Go through the [apex integration services](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services) trailhead

There is also a superbadge for [data integration](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_integration)  which you should go through to get more hands on work.

Finally for your question

1. Get the URL, request, response schema from end system
2. Agree on an authentication mechanism(oAuth based flows)
3. Test the services using sample request/response through tools like postman
4. If 3 works, write apex classes to integrate from within salesforce
5. Add the end point URL to remote site settings
6. Create named credentials for authenicating the end system
7. Use #6 in your apex class and call the external system

Before going down coding route i would check if we can achieve the same using configuration ways using one of below

1. Platform events
2. CDC - change data capture
3. Outbound messaging
4. External Services
5. External Objects